# Unable to create nested Syslog filter with NOT condition

Tags: linux, syslog, rsyslog

I have a syslog filter setup in my syslog.conf file and data is getting filtered and coming in.

```
source s_network {
tcp(port(6514) max-connections(100) keep-alive(yes) tls( key_file("/opt/certs/cert.key") cert_file("/opt/certs/cert.crt") ca-dir("/opt/certs/") peer_verify(optional-untrusted)) flags(no-multi-line));

filter filter_type1 {match("testString");};
destination 35_destination_35 { file("/Import/in/35/35_dest$R_YEAR$R_MONTH$R_DAY$R_HOUR"); };
log {source(s_network); filter(filter_type1 ); destination(35_destination_35);};
```

I wanted to create a negate filter to capture anything that is missed by this(filter_type1) filter.

```
filter f_test2 {not filter( filter_type1);};
destination 28_destination_28 { file("/Import/in/28/28_dest$R_YEAR$R_MONTH$R_DAY$R_HOUR"); };
log {source(s_network); filter(f_test2 ); destination(28_destination_28);};
```

Is this even possible? I do not get any syntax error and the service is running as expected. However the filter **f_test2** is still giving me **filter_type1** data. It should essesntially give my anything not captured by **filter_type1** filter.